# Stop Kendo from converting times to local timezone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, kendo-ui

How can I prevent Kendo from converting the `DateTime` object I pass it to the user's local timezone?

I'm using `Kendo UI` along with my `MVC` project. In my view I can use `C#` to print out the date/time by simply doing the following:

```
@Model.EndDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt)
```

However, some parts of my project I am using Kendo Templates which require me to use Kendo's `.toString()` method to properly format the date. The problem with this is it converts it to the local timezone of the browser which I don't want it to do.
Here is how I am using kendo to display the date/time:

```
<script id="DetailTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    #= kendo.toString(EndDate, "g") #
</script>
```

From what I've read, it's actually JavaScript itself that is by default changing the timzone. Is there a way I can parse the dates before they are used that locks them into their original timezone?

Comment: Dates don't have a timezone, they are UTC. However, the built-in *toString* uses the host timezone when building the string for display. How are you storing the original timezone?

Comment: @RobG Thanks for that information, I didn't realize that they didn't store timezones. I decided to just go with moment.js to specify the timezone I want the date in.

Comment: Supporting a specific timezone is fairly easy, but daylight saving gets a bit more interesting. If you're comfortable with a library that's ok too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to work around this, I decided to just use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) and [moment-timezone.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone).

I want all of my times to be ET so my kendo template now looks like this:

```
<script id="DetailTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    #: moment(EndDate).tz("America/New_York").format("M/DD/YYYY hh:mm A") #
</script>
```